# PHP. How to automatically include all existed files and get a variable data?

Tags: php, include, echo, file-exists

I need help with includes in PHP.

I have a group of files where each contains a variable $tariff_about.

```
<?php               
    include("tariffs/tariff-a1.php"); echo $tariff_about;
    include("tariffs/tariff-a2.php"); echo $tariff_about;
    include("tariffs/tariff-a3.php"); echo $tariff_about;
    include("tariffs/tariff-a4.php"); echo $tariff_about;
    include("tariffs/tariff-a5.php"); echo $tariff_about;
;?>
```

It would be nice to automatically include all existed files with 'tariff-a' prefix.

I understand that there is PHP file_exists function; however, I don't know how to make it work in this example with echo.

Help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use glob to get all the files matching a certain pattern, then loop and include.

```
$files = glob( 'tariffs/tariff-a*.php' );

foreach( $files as $file ) {
    include( $file );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Galen answer can be made more compact:

```
foreach(glob( 'tariffs/tariff-a*.php') as $file) {
    include $file;
}
```

The include is special statement and does not need the round brackets.